# How to express the digit place of a decimal number?

Tags: notation

I have a computer program which outputs decimal numbers with a one's place and one digit after the decimal point, for example 2.5 or 3.0. The program can only output a 0 or a 5 after the decimal, so if it computes 4.4 it will round this down to 4.0.

How can I best verbally articulate this limitation of the program? Something to the effect of "my program currently supports only a value of 5 or 0 in the digit after the decimal".

I am just looking for the right way to say this since I don't know what the digit after the decimal is called.

Comment: I would use something like the output of the function is of the form $k/2$ for some integer $k$,though not quite sure if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right place to ask such a question, but I would say:

The program rounds to the nearest half integer.